# In Google App Engine, how can I see the logs related to the error code APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When I try to deploy my Google App Engine Flex application I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED

error: exit status 1
```

Where can I go to see the lots related to this error? I checked stackdriver related to the the app engine service but didn't see anything.

Comment: Which log are you checking?

Comment: @JohnHanley  I have been looking at the ones here: console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer

Specifically under app engine and then the service name. Although now that  I click on the specific version it's showing logs that weren't coming up in search before. I'm looking through them now but no search results for that specific error code showed up.

Comment: That error is printed by the CLI and might not match what the service is logging. Look for anything that is an error at the time you ran the command to deploy. If it down, not the last message in Stackdriver and run the deploy again. Wait a few minutes and check Stackdriver.

Comment: You should be able to find something with the filters you specified. Update the question once you find it.

Comment: After redeploying and looking through the logs several times I didn't see anything to indicate what caused this error. Eventually, it stopped happening after reworking my Dockerfile a bit.  Still not sure what the cause was or why there's not much info about this  error code on the internet.